# Importing multiple CSV files into a single sheet in Excel using VBA (can currently only do 1)

Tags: excel, vba

I've designed a VBA enabled workbook that allows the user to select a .csv file (which is a customer export from another system) and then it basically processes it to produce a number of different user cohorts, based upon various user defined criteria etc.

It all works really nicely. However, it can only process one .csv file at a time.

The current approach I've taken basically imports the content of the selected CSV file into a new sheet, and then I simply interrogate that data and do what I need to with it. However, having not used VBA for a very long time, I'm not sure how to build on what I've already coded, to allow for the selection of multiple CSV files.

```
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        'We only want to allow CSV files as this is what the ADT comes in
        .Filters.Add "ADT CSV Files", "*.csv", 1
        'Show the dialog box
        .Show

    'Error check in case user cancels dialog box to prevent type-mismatch error

    If (.SelectedItems.Count = 0) Then

        Range("C19").Value = "File selection aborted."
    Else
        'Store in fullpath variable
        Range("C19").Value = "Processing..."
        fullpath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End If
    End With

    'A final check to make sure that the user hasn't done anything odd and somehow selected an invalid file format

    If InStr(fullpath, ".csv") = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Range("J26").Value = "Source File:"
    Range("J27").Value = fullpath

    'Now we grab the data from the file and import it into a new sheet within workbook

    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    Ws.Name = "ADT Data"

    'The ADT seems to be using fairly standard formatting conditions, so the following should surfice

         With Ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & fullpath, Destination:=Ws.Range("$A$1"))

        .Name = "ADT Data"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

    End With

    'Now we trigger our main triage processes

    Call Extract
```

I'm assuming I need to add the selected files to an array, and then loop through them, but with my VBA knowledge as it is I'm not sure how to achieve.

Comment: Set `.AllowMultiSelect = True` and then iterate over `.SelectedItems`.  See how you have `.SelectedItems.Item(1)` ?  Instead of that, do a `For i = 1 to .SelectedItems.Count` and then reference each selected .csv with `.SelectedItems.Item(i)`

Comment: `.allowmultiselect=true`, store the names of each file, then loop through those file names like `for each item In .SelectedItems`, appending to the lastrow+1 in the workbook

Answer (score 2):

You have this option set to false

.AllowMultiSelect = False

I would create an object to refer to the FileDialog

`'Declare a variable as a FileDialog object and set it like so:
Dim fd As FileDialog
'Create a FileDialog object as a File Picker dialog box.
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)`

You can then iterate over the SelectedItems collection of the fd object.

`For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems`

Then do your operation on each file that was selected.

The AllowMultiSelect documentation has some good info.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa210129(v%3Doffice.11)

Hope this helps.